# mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement (one function works other does not)

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

This question has been answered before but not in the same format.

I am trying to create an object method to grab a database row.  I keep getting the titled error.  The odd thing is that if i call the same code of the function directly in the parent class method it works.  Here are the two examples.

Example 1: works
Function called from seperate PHP page like:
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);

```
$found_user = User::authenticate($email, $password);
```

Here is the function that is working. (I setup the function as I would have if I were making a reusable function to test if my code was bad)

```
public static function authenticate($username="", $password="") {

    $db = Database::getInstance();
    $mysqli = $db->getConnection();

    $field = 'email';

    $sql_query  = "SELECT * ";
    $sql_query .= "FROM `".static::$table_name."`";
    $sql_query .= "WHERE {$field}=? ";
    $sql_query .= "LIMIT 1";

    $stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();

    if (!$stmt->prepare($sql_query)) {
        $error = "Errormessage: " . $mysqli->error;
        return $error;
    }

    if (!$stmt->prepare($sql_query)) {
        $error = "Errormessage: " . $stmt->error;
        return $error;
    } else {
        $stmt->prepare($sql_query);

        $valueType = gettype($username);

        if ($valueType == 'string') {
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);  
        } else if ($valueType == 'integer') {
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $username);  
        } else if ($valueType == 'double') {
            $stmt->bind_param('d', $username);  
        } else {
            $stmt->bind_param('b', $username);  
        }

        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();

        return $result->fetch_object();
    }       
}
```

Now, if I call the function in the same method but from an extended class (parent class is User which extends DatabaseOptions).  The functions are written as such:

```
public static function authenticate($username="", $password="") {
    $dbObject = static::get_row('email', $username);

    if (isset($dbObject)) {
        return $dbObject;
    }
}
```

The function within the DatabaseObject:

```
public function get_row($field, $value) {
    $db = Database::getInstance();
    $mysqli = $db->getConnection();

    $sql_query  = "SELECT * ";
    $sql_query .= "FROM `".static::$table_name."`";
    $sql_query .= "WHERE {$field}=? ";
    $sql_query .= "LIMIT 1";

    $stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();

    if (!$stmt->prepare($sql_query)) {
        $error = "Errormessage: " . $stmt->error;
        return $error;
    } else {
        $stmt->prepare($sql_query);

        $valueType = gettype($value);

        if ($valueType == 'string') {
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $value); 
        } else if ($valueType == 'integer') {
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $value); 
        } else if ($valueType == 'double') {
            $stmt->bind_param('d', $value); 
        } else {
            $stmt->bind_param('b', $value); 
        }

        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();

        return $result->fetch_object();
    }           
}
```

Comment: Made an edit.  Noticed I had: $stmt->bind_param('s', $value); in there after the if/else if statements.  Even after removing still have same error

Comment: Why is there a second `$stmt->prepare($sql_query);` in the else branch?

Comment: Try getting rid of `$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();` and instead just do `if(!$stmt  = $mysqli->prepare($sql_query))`  The docs for `stmt_init()` are a little vague as to the return value (they say it returns an 'object').  It may be a mysqli statement object, though using `stmt_init` is definitely not necessary. Also, it doesn't seem like just calling `prepare` on a statement object is doing anything to _that_ object.

Comment: Thanks VolkerK and watcher.  I made both edits.  Just removing the 2nd prepare that was in the else statement maintained the same error as before.  Continuing onto watcher's suggestion led to: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function get_row($field, $value) {
    $db = Database::getInstance();
    $mysqli = $db->getConnection();

    $sql_query  = "SELECT * ";
    $sql_query .= "FROM `".static::$table_name."`";
    $sql_query .= "WHERE {$field}=? ";
    $sql_query .= "LIMIT 1";

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql_query)) {
        $valueType = gettype($value);

        if ($valueType == 'string') {
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $value); 
        } else if ($valueType == 'integer') {
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $value); 
        } else if ($valueType == 'double') {
            $stmt->bind_param('d', $value); 
        } else {
            $stmt->bind_param('b', $value); 
        }

        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        return $result->fetch_object();
    } else {
        $error = "Errormessage: " . $stmt->error;
        return $error;
    }           
}
```

The issue with the original code was the fact that I was using bind_result($row), where the row that i was pulling from in the DB has multiple values that would need to be bound.  As `$result = $stmt->get_result` and then returned a `fetch_object();`.